# How to type get error response data from axios AsyncThunk

Tags: typescript, express, error-handling, axios

I am having a hard time access the error response data, The code worked on javascript I moved to typescript now things are confusing. Currently i get 'error' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)

```
export const registerClient = createAsyncThunk('clients/register', async (userData: object, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post('/web/client/register', userData);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.error);
  }
});
```

**Things i tried**

- `return rejectWithValue((error as any).response.data.error);` - Unexpected any, I can't use any type
- Tried creating a new interface below code - got this error, `error' is of type 'unknown'`

```
interface ErrorResponse {
  error: string;
}

const errorResponse: ErrorResponse = error.response.data;
return rejectWithValue(errorResponse.error);
```

Anyone has a proper solution for this
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Typescript complains that error is of `unknown` type when it's in strict mode.

So you can either set the type to any in `catch(error: any)` to make the error go away or change
the flag `useUnknownInCatchVariables` to false in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false   
}
```